# Decomposing every cycle using Spectral Analysis

Tags: r

I'm completely new to the world of Spectral Analysis, and I'm trying to isolate all the cycles from a time series, similar to what is shown here (the link to the image is found [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Singular_spectrum_analysis)):

[image]

I am attempting to learn the topic better by experiment using datasets in R, but none of the guides on the internet seem to explain exactly what I am looking for (using sine, cosine wave, and trend to explain time series movements).

Using the following example,

```
library(tidyverse)

tseries <- as.data.frame(LakeHuron)  %>%
  mutate(year = c(1875:1972) )

ggplot(data = tseries , aes(x = year , y= as.numeric(x))) + 
  geom_line() + ylab("level")
```

Gives:

[image]

How would I proceed? I would appreciate any help.